# Solve ......................................................................

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, systems-of-equations, radicals

[image: This is the question]

[image: This is the answer]

This is what I did
[image: Hate to type hence this]

Can anyone tell me what's wrong me or the question?

Comment: Hi @Ajay! $$\color{red}{\Large\text{Welcome to Math.SE!}}$$ Don't worry about it now (since you're new) but you might like to know that we prefer to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here (e.g. `$\theta$` for $\theta$).

Comment: However, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+sqrt%28x%2Fy%29-sqrt%28y%2Fx%29%3D3%2F2%2C+x%2Bxy%2By%3D9 gives $(-9,-9/4)$ and $(4,1)$ as answers. So, $|x_1|+|x_2|=|-9|+|4|=13$, and the image says the answer is 5...

Comment: Is there any other way of solving this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did the case $y=4x$, and got answers $x=1$ and $x=-\frac{9}{4}$. Neither is a solution of the original equation. It is easy to verify that when $y=4x$ we have $\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}-\sqrt{\frac{y}{x}}=-\frac{3}{2}$.

When you squared, you introduced *extraneous roots*. Only $x=4y$ leads to a solution of the system.

Comment: So as I squared the equation I added a new root which do not satisfy the original equation.  Then how should I solve this?

Comment: There is a second possibility that you found but did not analyze, namely $x=4y$. That *does* satisfy the first equation. Proceed like you did with the extraneous $y=4x$.

Comment: I used that already. but at that time answer was 13. Because Absolute value of -9 is 9. They should have given abs(x1 + x2) to get answer 5. That's what I think.

Comment: I agree. The answer is wrong, and certainly $|x_1+x_2|$ would make it right, but that is not what they asked for.

Comment: So The question was wrong. Anyways Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Well, the answer was wrong, it should be $13$.

Comment: Yep. Can you solve this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665823/find-the-lcm-of-3-numbers-given-hcf-of-each-2.